# Hide specific listview item while searching (Filter)

Tags: android, listview

I have two same value in my listview.I hide one value from it.But When i search that record in searchbar(I Used Filer)then it display those both records and this issue is only in Android 8.0 Oreo.So please help me how  can I hide that record while searching.

This is my code by which I hide duplicate record from listview (It is working for all OS except Android 8.0).

```
 String Name=stationlist.get(position).getStation_name();
    if(Name.equals("Old High Court Interchange")){
        System.out.println("Search station name : "+ flag);

        if(flag==true){
            holder.mainll.setVisibility(View.GONE);//mainll is LinearLayout
            flag = false;
        }

    }
    else {
        holder.mainll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        flag = true;
    }
```

Comment: is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue.This is code which I have added in my FilterResults method of valueFilter class(extend by Filter).

```
if(filterList.get(i).getStation_name().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
            {
                //ADD PLAYER TO FILTERED PLAYERS
               // filteredPlayers.add(filterList.get(i));Dharmesh


                if(filterList.get(i).getStation_name().equals("Old High Court Interchange")){

                    if(flagSearch==true){
                        //.mainll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        filteredPlayers.add(filterList.get(i));
                        flagSearch = false;
                    }else{

                    }

                }else {
                    filteredPlayers.add(filterList.get(i));
                    //flag = true;
                }
            }
```